# Ansible expect is not sending response

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-playbook, yaml

I'm new to ansible and trying it by writing an ansible playbook for installing graphite, as a part of it I have the `graphite-manage syncdb` command which I would like to automate.

I wrote this task to automatically answer to the promts but for some reason it get stuck and breaks on timeout. `"msg": "command exceeded timeout"` and it seems like it doesn't send my response to the promted answer. 
I though maybe its the format i used and I checked the samples on ansible docs but Its really simple without additional information.

Here is my sample, please take a look:

```
---
    - hosts: localhost
      tasks:
      - name: graphite-web syncdb
        expect:
          command: sudo graphite-manage syncdb
          responses:
            'Would you like to create one now? (yes/no):': 'yes'
            'Username (leave blank to use "root"):': '\n'
            'Email address:': 'test@test.com'
            'Password:': '123123'
            'Password (again):': '123123'
```

This is the log output I recieved:

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sudo graphite-manage syncdb", "delta": "0:00:30.107393", "end": "2018-11-12 15:39:01.897639", "msg": "command exceeded timeout", "rc": null, "start": "2018-11-12 15:38:31.790246", "stdout": "\u001b[36;1mOperations to perform:\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[1m  Synchronize unmigrated apps: \u001b[0maccount, cli, render, whitelist, metrics, url_shortener, dashboard, composer, events, browser\r\n\u001b[1m  Apply all migrations: \u001b[0madmin, contenttypes, tagging, auth, sessions\r\n\u001b[36;1mSynchronizing apps without migrations:\u001b[0m\r\n  Creating tables...\r\n    Running deferred SQL...\r\n  Installing custom SQL...\r\n\u001b[36;1mRunning migrations:\u001b[0m\r\n  No migrations to apply.\r\n\r\nYou have installed Django's auth system, and don't have any superusers defined.\r\nWould you like to create one now? (yes/no): ", "stdout_lines": ["\u001b[36;1mOperations to perform:\u001b[0m", "\u001b[1m  Synchronize unmigrated apps: \u001b[0maccount, cli, render, whitelist, metrics, url_shortener, dashboard, composer, events, browser", "\u001b[1m  Apply all migrations: \u001b[0madmin, contenttypes, tagging, auth, sessions", "\u001b[36;1mSynchronizing apps without migrations:\u001b[0m", "  Creating tables...", "    Running deferred SQL...", "  Installing custom SQL...", "\u001b[36;1mRunning migrations:\u001b[0m", "  No migrations to apply.", "", "You have installed Django's auth system, and don't have any superusers defined.", "Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): "]}
```

Thanks a lot for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys in `response` map are regular expressions, so `?` and `(...)` are treated as regexp control characters resulting in no match.

If you really want to pass the whole string, you should use:

```
responses:
  'Would you like to create one now\? \(yes/no\):': 'yes'
```

But given there is no more `create on now` text in any other prompt, you can use:

```
responses:
  'create one now': 'yes'
```

Comment: thanks a lot that one helped.It also means that I can select only some part of the text in the prompt and not the entire one.